# How many active, simultaneous connections can a web server accept?

Tags: sql, sql-server, wordpress

I know this is a difficult question but here it is, in context:

Our company has a request to build a WordPress website for a certain client. The caveat is that, on one day per year, for a period of about 20 minutes, 5,000 - 10,000 people will attempt to access the home page of this website. Their purpose: Only to acquire an outbound link to another site.

My concern is, no matter what kind of hosting we provide, the server may reject the connections after a certain number of connections are reached.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: That doesn't depend on WordPress but on the system your server uses for incoming connections (like Apache)

Comment: All depend on server power (how good machine is this) and server configuration

Comment: All depends on how you host the site. Sounds like a perfect case for cloud based hosting. Using something like Azure means you could scale up just for that 1 day a year without really having to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

This does not depend on WordPress. WordPress is basically software to render webpages: it helps you to quickly modify the *content* content of a page. Other software like for instance Apache accepts connections and redirects the calls to for instance WordPress.

Apache can be configured to accept more connections. I think the default is about 200. If that's bad really depends. If the purpose is only to give another URL, you can say that connections will be terminated fast. So that's not really an issue. If on the other hand you want to generate an entire page using PHP and MySQL it can take some time before a client is satisfied. In that case 200 connections are perhaps not sufficient.

As B-Lat points out. You can use cloud computing platforms like Google App Engine or Microsoft Azure that provide a lot of server power. But only bill their clients on the consumption on these resources. In other words you can accept thousands of connections at once. But you don't need to pay for the other days when clients visit your website less often.

Comment: Note sure if Apps Engine or Azure would fly well with a WordPress install? We may need to upgrade our server contract.

Comment: @JPate: There are entire webpage dedicated on how you can install WordPress smoothly on such a platform: http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/

Comment: Fascinating. Never have looked into this.